# Recover Domain from Failed Company

Tags: web-hosting, domain-transfer

I have an old client who wanted to transfer hosting companies. However, the company he has managing his domain has gone under and won't respond to phone calls or emails, and their account manager is down.

Never have come across a situation like this, what can I do to get his domain to a different company?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, find out who the actual domain registrar is.  You may be able to contact the registrar directly for assistance in getting the domain ownership ironed out and will likely have to provide proof of domain ownership.

The new hosting company may have experience in dealing with these situations.  Contacting their Support department may also be a good step to take.

There is information on the [ICANN site about registrar issues](http://www.icann.org/en/dispute-resolution/#services).  They will not actually resolve the issue but may be able to facilitate getting it taken care of.

Comment: We're attempting this, hopefully it works.